# What does `getComputedStyle` return and how to iterate over it?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, getcomputedstyle

Looking to get all the styles of a specific element via JavaScript. `getComputedStyle` works fine, however I'm confused what type of object it returns and how to best iterate over it. While some other answers have suggested iterating it over an array with a `forEach` loop as most of the properties are integer based, what are the other properties of the returned object?

For example logging the styles of an element with:

```
const styles = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.foo'))
for (let property in styles) {
    if (styles.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      console.log('property:', property, 'value:', styles[property]);
    }
  }
```

Returns (abbreviated for brevity):

```
property: 0 value: align-content
property: 1 value: align-items
property: 2 value: align-self
property: 3 value: alignment-baseline
property: 4 value: animation-delay
...
property: alignContent value: normal
property: alignItems value: normal
```

It would make sense if it is truly an array, as many of the properties are index based, however after index 319 it goes back to keys of strings, `alignContent` is the next key of the returned object.

Additionally is there a way to get only the declared style of an element and not *all* of the computed ones?

Comment: Have you tried reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to see what kind of object it returns?

Comment: You should not ask two questions in the same post. Makes it hard to have a single correct answer.  Computed style is one thing, declared styles are something else. Please update your question with which one is your initial concern and how you're trying to use it.

Comment: Getting the list of rules that apply to an element is very complicated, why do you need that? You basically need to iterate over all the rules in the document using `document.styleSheets` and then check if each rule matches your element using `element.matches(rule.selectorText)`,

Answer (score 0):

The [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method returns a live [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) object.

Here's one way to iterate through its properties:

```js
let p = document.querySelector("p");
let showProps = (list) => {
  let out = "";
  [...list].forEach(s => { out += `${s} → ${list[s]}\n`; });
  return out;
}
let comp = getComputedStyle(p);
console.log(showProps(comp));
console.log(comp.getPropertyValue("font"));
console.log(showProps(p.style));
```

```css
p      { color:gray; font:bold 12pt fantasy; }
#brown { color:brown; }
.green { color:green; }
```

```html
<p style="color:red" class="green" id="brown">Hello world</p>
```

In this example, I've created a `<p>` element and defined its color in four different places. I've also set the `font` shorthand property, specifying things like the `font-size`. CSS prioritizes the `style` attribute's red color, which you can see in the rendering.

The JavaScript code gets the computed style for that element and then runs that through a function that converts it to a proper array and iterates through each of its properties, adding a new line with "property → value" to the `out` variable for each one. This is then returned and dumped to the console.

You can also do `comp.getPropertyValue(property)` to get the value of a given property, e.g. "font-size" (which JS additionally offers as the `comp.fontSize` property). The second console output in the example code shows the contents of `comp.getPropertyValue("font")`.

One thing you'll notice is that units are converted in storage: `red` became `rgb(255, 0, 0)`, `bold` became its numeric weight of `700`, and `12pt` became `16px` (at least on my system; this varies by your setup). You may also have noticed that, as a [shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties), `font` is not represented in the iterated dump, though its components are.

---

You also asked for a list of just the declared properties. This is quite complicated because these can come from a linked stylesheet, a `<style>` element, or the `style` attribute to the element. Within the former two, it could be inherited.

I suppose you could do `base = getComputedStyle(document.createElement("p"))` and then compare it with your `<p>` element's computed style, but that still inherits stuff from e.g. `<style>p { color:gray }</style>` (which I assume you want).

If all you're really looking for are the inline styles from the HTML tag's `style` attribute, that's as simple as iterating just on that: `p.style` is also a CSSStyleDeclaration object. This is the final console log in the example. As you can see, only the red color shows up, using the value as specified rather than as computed.

Answer (score -2):

Here is how you can iterate over it. For more detail description check this:
https://css-tricks.com/how-to-get-all-custom-properties-on-a-page-in-javascript/

```js
const isSameDomain = (styleSheet) => {
  if (!styleSheet.href) {
    return true;
  }

  return styleSheet.href.indexOf(window.location.origin) === 0;
};

const isStyleRule = (rule) => rule.type === 1;

const getCSSCustomPropIndex = () =>
  [...document.styleSheets]
    .filter(isSameDomain)
    .reduce(
      (finalArr, sheet) =>
        finalArr.concat(
          [...sheet.cssRules].filter(isStyleRule).reduce((propValArr, rule) => {
            const props = [...rule.style]
              .map((propName) => [
                propName.trim(),
                rule.style.getPropertyValue(propName).trim(),
              ])
              .filter(([propName]) => propName.indexOf("--") === 0);
            return [...propValArr, ...props];
          }, [])
        ),
      []
    )
    
    console.log(getCSSCustomPropIndex());
```

```css
:root{
  --primary: #112233;
  --secondary: #222222;
}
```

Comment: This answer iterates over the items in a website's local stylesheets, which is entirely different from iterating over a live [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) object (which is what `getComputedStyle` returns).